# Move images from computer to usb thumb drive from terminal window ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, usb, transfer, cp

New to Ubuntu and would like clear instructions on how to copy files (images) from my ubuntu machine to a usb drive. I can see the drive using lsblk as sdb1. Do i need to mount and why do i need to do so? Simply put move files in a directory off the machine onto a usb drive. I can do this with the GUI but i am ssh into the machine and this is why i need to know from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

**I make some assumptions...**

- all of the pictures that you want to copy are in the ~/Pictures folder
- only pictures are in the ~/Pictures folder
- some pictures may be in sub-folders
- the pictures could be .jpg, .png, or something else
- you want to retain the same folder structure
- you want to retain the same file attributes
- you don't want to delete the original files
- you know the mount point of your USB drive, and it's currently mounted
- you have enough space on the USB drive

**To copy everything...**

```
mkdir /media/$USER/mount_point_to_USB_drive/Pictures
cp -an ~/Pictures/* /media/$USER/mount_point_to_USB_drive/Pictures
```

**If you only want one kind of image, say .jpg's, then...**

```
mkdir /media/$USER/mount_point_to_USB_drive/Pictures
cp -an ~/Pictures/*.jpg /media/$USER/mount_point_to_USB_drive/Pictures
```

Answer (score 0):

You `usb` is already mounted at `/media/$USER/<name_of_usb>` so just run this command to move those files. I presume the images are in `/home/$USER/Pictures` so run this from the terminal:

If in another location different from that of the image files

```
mv /home/$USER/Pictures/<file_name>.<png | jpeg> /media/$USER/<name_of_usb>

# Example
mv /home/$USER/mypicture.png /media/$USER/george_usb
```

If in the same location as the image files then do:

```
mv <file_name>.<png | jpeg> /media/$USER/<name_of_usb>

 # Example
mv mypicture.png /media/$USER/george_usb
```

Moving multiple files at once use:

```
mv *.png    /media/$USER/george_usb
```

Comment: You may wish to confirm with the user... copy or move/delete? Do you mean to use `cp`? And maybe account for recursing (`cp -r`) into folders that contain pictures?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use sudo for a simple move/copy.

Comment: Thanks but I see `move` keyword in the OP hence my `mv` command

Comment: @wjandrea doesn't moving into `/media` folder need this

Comment: True, but that still doesn't account for images in folders.

Comment: I'm not at my machine now, but I believe everything in `/media/$USER` is owned by `$USER` and has perms 755.

Comment: @wjandrea I will check also

Comment: @wjandrea your right just updated my answer

Comment: /media/$USER is owned by the user. sodu isn't needed to write there unless the usb folder  itself is owned by root. (I had this issue when using sudo to copy system files)